# Autoit Recorder not available

Tags: automation, autoit, autoit-recorder

From [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-script-editor/downloads/) I downloaded:

1. [SciTE4AutoIt3.exe](https://www.autoitscript.com/cgi-bin/getfile.pl?../autoit3/scite/download/SciTE4AutoIt3.exe)
2. [SciTE.exe](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/scite/download/Win9x/SciTE.exe)

But AutoIt Recorder is not in the tools menu. Also tried downloading AutoIt Recorder, though I could not. How to get AutoIt Recorder?

Comment: Have you saved the script your trying to create? The tools menu will not show the Au3Recorder until you do so, unless you downloaded SciTE - light.

Comment: Exactly, you have to have a blank script to write to the script. So, you will need to have a saved file to have Au3Recorder put the code into. Try just saving the file before doing anything, then checking tools -> Au3Recorder

Comment: You use tools on an unsaved file, it must be saved to a location on your computer first. Also, if that does not work then you will need to download the full version of the SciTE editor here - https://www.autoitscript.com/cgi-bin/getfile.pl?../autoit3/scite/download/SciTE4AutoIt3.exe

Answer (score 54):

As of AutoIt v3.3.14.1 AU3Recorder is not included anymore. The only way is:

1. [Download AutoIt v3.3.14.0](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/files/archive/autoit/autoit-v3.3.14.0.zip).
2. Copy 
   `autoit-v3.3.14.0.zip\install\Extras\Au3Record`
    to 
   `{AutoIt-Install-Dir}\Extras\Au3Record`.
3. Start AU3Recorder:

   - Run `{AutoIt-Install-Dir}\Extras\Au3Record\Au3Record.exe`.
   - Or open SciTE and click `Tools > AU3Recorder` (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>):
     [image]

Notes:

- Version 3.3.14.0 *has* AU3Recorder.
- Version 3.3.14.2 does *not*.
- [Changelog / history](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/history.htm) does not mention it.
- [Explained here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/173818-autoit-v33142-released/#comment-1261749) and [here](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/176009-where-is-au3recordexe/).

Answer (score 9):

> It has been removed from the main installer from v3.3.14.1 as it triggers many AV false positives. You can find an old version here:
>
> https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/files/archive/autoit/autoit-v3.3.14.0.zip
>
> A little explanation of the rather strange link above:
>
> If we give you a direct link to the file (or the zip file which includes it) the site gets flagged as hosting malware (yes really!) - so what you have is a link to the AutoIt archive page and the name of the zip file you need to download from it.

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/176009-where-is-au3recordexe/

It is then located in the zip file at:
.\install\Extras\Au3Record

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might be looking for the AU3Recorder.  You'll find this in one of the following paths (depending on your build), so long as you went with a full installation.

- C:\Program Files\AutoIt3\Extras\Au3Record
- C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\Extras\Au3Record

Comment: This is no longer included in those folders (and yes, I chose the full installation).

Answer (score 0):

1. Install AutoIt v3 (This is the latest version as for now)
2. After installation:
   2.1 Click Windows Start icon -> Click "AutoIt v3" -> Click "Browse Extras"
   2.2 Extras folder of AutoIt will open in Windows Explorer. Click on "Au3Record" folder -> Double click on "Au3Record.exe"
3. AU3Record will open

Another way using AutoIt Script Editor(SciTE4AutoIt3.exe):

1. Download AutoIt Script Editor from https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-script-editor/downloads/
2. Install it
3. After installation:
   3.1 Open AutoIt Script Editor
   3.2. Click Tools menu -> click AU3Recorder from context menu

Comment: For me it is not there